# Persistent Storage Error - Property list invalid for format: 200

Tags: swift

The app is a list much like the To Do List app. It works fine however when I added the code with regards to persistent data (NSUser Defaults) I encounter an error. I have the error and my code below. (I have commented the NSUserdefaults part). I was hoping you can guide me and provide some answers.

> Error: 2015-01-19 22:26:40.783 Shoplisters[62316:22301266] Property
>   list invalid for format: 200 (property lists cannot contain objects of
>   type 'CFType') 2015-01-19 22:26:40.783 Shoplisters[62316:22301266]
>   Attempt to set a non-property-list object ( "", "" ) as an
>   NSUserDefaults/CFPreferences value for key shoppingList 2015-01-19
>   22:26:40.785 Shoplisters[62316:22301266] *** Terminating app due to
>   uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attempt to
>   insert non-property list object ( "", "" ) for key
>   shoppingList'

Code:
    import UIKit

```
var shoppingList:[ShopList] = listData

class ShopListTableViewController: UITableViewController {

@IBAction func cancelToListView(segue:UIStoryboardSegue) {
dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
//actions for cancel button
}

@IBAction func saveListDetail(segue:UIStoryboardSegue) {

let listDetailsViewController = segue.sourceViewController as     AddNewListTableViewController

//add the new list to the shopping list array
shoppingList.append(listDetailsViewController.listDetails)

//NSUserdefaults
//let fixedShoppingList = shoppingList
//NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(fixedShoppingList,  forKey: "shoppingList")
//NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()

//update the table view
let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: shoppingList.count-1, inSection: 0)
tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)

//hide the detail view controller
dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)


}


override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()


//if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("shoppingList") != nil {

//shoppingList =  NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("shoppingList") as  [ShopList]

//}


}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
// Return the number of sections.
return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection     section: Int) -> Int {
// Return the number of rows in the section.

return shoppingList.count

}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath     indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("listCell",    forIndexPath: indexPath) as ShoppingListTableViewCell

//fill the prototype cell with the ff values:
var list = shoppingList[indexPath.row] as ShopList
cell.listNameLabel.text = list.name
cell.totalBudgetLabel.text = list.budget
cell.barColor.image = imageForColors(list.barColors)

return cell

}
```

Data:

```
import Foundation

import UIKit

class ShopList: NSObject {
var name:String
var budget:String
var barColors:String

init(name:String, budget:String, barcolor:String) {
self.name = name
self.budget = budget
self.barColors = barcolor
super.init()
}
}
```

Comment: You can only put elements into NSUserDefaults that comply to NSCoding. CFType does not. You need to wrap it into e.g. NSData or the like.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Im actually new to iOS and swift. can you provide a sample to my existing code? Not sure how to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply save/restore your settings with the following pattern:

```
let kString = "string"
let kInt = "int"
```

I declare these constants on global level. Swift does not have `#define`. Also I augment these constants with the camel case chars of the related class. E.g. for `class MyFancyClass` I would name the first `kMFCstring`.

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject("string data", forKey: kString)
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(4711, forKey: kInt)
```

This would save "string data" and 4711 to the defaults. Note that there are different methods for int, float, object etc. See the help or auto-completion. There is also a synchronize method which enforces saving of the settings to the file, but the OS will do that automatically when ever it's useful (e.g. when the program terminates).

```
let stringVal = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey(kString)! as String
let intVal = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey(kInt)! as String
```

This will restore the values. It's simply the reverse for the previous set-methods.

For types that are not object you can create a container. One possibility is to use `NSValue`.

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(NSValue(NSMakeRect(1,2,3,4), forKey: "myRect")
```

Check the help for `NSValue` what else can be packed inside.

Comment: So basically are you saying that I cannot use shoppingList variable above? var shoppingList = [ShopList(name: "Add New List", budget: "$0.00", barcolor: "")]

Comment: Yes.You need to convert the elements in the array, e.g. pack them into an array of NSValue.